# Can't get basic Powershell script running inside Team City

Tags: powershell, teamcity, powershell-1.0

Here's my configuration:
[image]

On the build log, I only see the output of the first two lines, and then "Process exited with code 0" as the last output of this build step.

I tried opening a terminal in the build server in the SYSTEM account (using [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649)), since Team City is configured to run under said account. Then, I created a Test.ps1 file with the same content and ran a command just like Team City's:

```
[Step 1/4] Starting: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -Command - <C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell5129275380148486045.ps1 && exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

(except for the path to the .ps1 file and the cmd.exe initial part, of course). I saw the output of the two first lines, and then the terminal disappeared all of a sudden!

Where did I mess up? I'm new to Powershell, by the way.

Comment: Have you set the Execution Policy to allow your script?

Comment: I chose "Put script into Powershell stdin with -Command arguments" to avoid that. Besides, if it can run the first two lines, I'd think permissions are OK, or do I need extra permissions to run conditional logic? That would be quite crazy :P

Comment: I have no context for this tool, but I wonder if it's having issues with multiline stdin? Try replacing conditional with the following (one-liner) to see if you get different results: if ("1" -eq "1") { write-host "test" } else { write-host "else test" }

Comment: When I try that script with a similar command line, it all works fine.  Try replacing the `&& exit ...` with `&& pause` to see if you can see the last the "Ok, nothing to see..." line before the window closes.  Or you could just change the `/c` to `/k` so the window will remain - just to help debug this.

Comment: I think your script is too hilarious, try a less hilarious script :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The stdin command option of Powershell has some weirdness around multiline commands like that.

You script in the following form would work:

```
write-host "test"
write-host "test2"
if("1" -eq "1"){write-host "test3 in if"} else {write-host "test4 in else"}
```

The ideal way would be to use the `Script : File` option in TeamCity which will will run the script you specify using the `-File` parameter to Powershell.

If you don't want to have a file and having VCS, in the current setup, change `Script Execution Mode` to `Execute .ps1 file with -File argument`.

Comment: You're right, if the `if-else` clauses are one-liners, it works. Wonder if this also happens with Powershell 2.0? Anyway, since code readability is priority, I decided to follow your second suggestion (which implied opening a terminal under the SYSTEM account, and running the following commands: 1) `powershell` 2) `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` 3) `exit`)

Comment: @dario_ramos - Happens upto powershell 3.0 CTP :)

Comment: Note that you can use ";" to separate multiple statements on a single line.

Comment: And the answer is still valid... unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem with inline powershell scripts with TeamCity (right up until the current version of 7.1.3). I've found the problem to be the tab character rather than multi-line statements. Try replacing the tab characters with spaces (while still remaining multi-line) and the script should run fine.

Comment: Perfect had the exact same problem. Hate tabs :)

Comment: Ditto with the tab problem. It causes the step to hang

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting the brace opening the block on the same line as the If.

I.e.,

```
If ('1' -eq '1') {
    ...
}
Else {
    ...
}
```

That's the usual styling you see with Powershell, and obviously, putting the braces on the next line can cause problems.