# TeamCity Powershell Runner - Unable to run Source Code

Tags: powershell, teamcity

Im trying to run some PS scripts using the Powershell Runner in TC and defining my own script as "Source Code" instead of a script file.
My script is as simple as:

```
"Hello World!"
```

Im running on Windows Server 2008 R2 and ive tried with to:

1. Run it as x86 + x64
2. Using "Execute .ps1 with '-File' argument" + "Put script into powershell stdin with "-Command -" arguments.
3. Ive set the security policy to Unrestricted in an attempt to get it to work, but no luck.

If I instead use a Command Line runner and for example writes:

```
powershell -Command Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

It works fine.

The errors im getting (depending on which of the 2 execution modes im using) are:

```
Starting: C:\...\cmd.exe /c C:\...\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -Command 
- "<C:\...\powershell3889347351955805274.ps1" && exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
in directory: C:\...\e18dda4054c166c7
'-' was specified with the -Command parameter; no other arguments to -Command are permitted.
```

OR

```
Starting: C:\...\cmd.exe /c C:\...\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -File     
"C:\...\powershell8264270201473986040.ps1" && exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
in directory: C:\...\e18dda4054c166c7
The term 'f' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
```

It looks to me like TC puts something in the actual script itself, but im not sure. Im stuck and I cant figure out what point im missing here :S.

Can anyone help?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165658/cant-get-basic-powershell-script-running-inside-team-city (Hit this first with my search keyworkds but real issue is that put into stdin mode chokes on some things, e.g., if blocks in TC 7.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this, but I noticed something pretty weird with the command that TeamCity was trying to run:

```
-NonInteractive -Command - "<C:\...\powershell3889347351955805274.ps1"
```

I did not see it adding the quotes for me, so I thought maybe TeamCity is trying to quote a path with space(s) in it ( would have helped if you hadn't redacted your path)

So I switched my agent to a path with a space in it and I got the same command, and yes, the same error. So TeamCity is quoting the path wrongly. It is including the `<` in the quotes while it should have been `<"c:\path with\space"`

I will see if I can file a bug for this ( if there isn't one)

Try moving your agent to a non-space path as a workaround.

Comment: Thx, this was driving me crazy. I had dismissed the path as it was in qoutes and didn't catch the "<" :).