# WebRequest fails on TeamCity with HTTP-400 error

Tags: powershell, teamcity, webrequest

I have a powershell script that makes a SOAP call to an API:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://***.***.***.***/iControl/iControlPortal.cgi")
$request.Method = "POST"
$request.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential @("username", "password")
$request.Proxy = new-object System.Net.WebProxy @("***.***.***.***", ****)
$request.PreAuthenticate = $true;
$request.CachePolicy = new-object System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy "NoCacheNoStore"

$payload = '<?xml version="1.0"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><soap:Body><q1:get_monitor_status xmlns:q1="urn:iControl:LocalLB/PoolMember"><pool_names href="#id1" /></q1:get_monitor_status><soapenc:Array id="id1"><Item>{0}</Item></soapenc:Array></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>' -f "my-pool"
$requestPayloadWriter = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $request.GetRequestStream()
$requestPayloadWriter.Write($payload)
$requestPayloadWriter.Flush()
$requestPayloadWriter.Close()

$responsePayloadReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
$pool_status = $responsePayloadReader.ReadToEnd()
$responsePayloadReader.Flush()
$responsePayloadReader.Close()

$pool_status
```

This works locally on my machine, but fails when I run it via TeamCity.
It does work when I remote into the agent and run script manually from the console.

The message I get from PowerShell is:

> Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote
>   server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Any suggestions on what could be going wrong or how to diagnose this further?
I was not able to capture any traffic using Fiddler, so any suggestions on that are also welcome.

Comment: Do you get any error info?  Have you seen this SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165658/cant-get-basic-powershell-script-running-inside-team-city

Comment: @KeithHill I do get an error response - I have now included it my question.

Comment: `I was not able to capture any traffic using Fiddler` <-- why not? you need to capture a working request and a non-working request and compare them

Comment: @wal is right. The error is coming from the server because it doesn't think your request is valid. The best way to debug that is to compare the non-working request with a working request in Fiddler.

Comment: @wal I can capture requests I've sent, but not requests originating from TeamCity.

Comment: @ArnoldZokas because the call originates from TeamCity? If yes, then put fiddler on the TeamCity box.

Comment: @wal That's what I did.

Comment: `I was not able to capture any traffic using Fiddler,` <-- why not?

Comment: With fiddler running on the agent box, I could capture other http traffic, but not agent traffic. I suspect TeamCity agent is bypassing local proxies. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, it turns out, the F5 API I was calling.
There is a bug in the version of F5 we are using: under certain conditions requests get rejected with a 400-response.

Nothing to do with TeamCity/Powershell.